# SKPolyline setColor not giving correct color

Tags: android, skmaps

I am using a method to create a color array however the `SKPolyline` is white instead of the desired pinkish color. Here's the code:

```
    public static float[] getPinkColorArray() {
       float[] colorArray = new float[4];
       colorArray[0] = 249f;
       colorArray[1] = 1f;
       colorArray[2] = 148f;
       colorArray[3] = 255f;

       return colorArray;
   }
```

I then use `polyline.setColor(floatArray);` and it creates a white polyline. If I use values 255, 0, 0, 255 I get a red line (which is correct).

tl;dr: How do I make a pink float array for an SKPolyline with values red:249, green:1, blue:148, no alpha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    SKPolyline polyline = new SKPolyline();
    // set the nodes on the polyline
    nodes = new ArrayList<SKCoordinate>();
    nodes.add(new SKCoordinate(-122.4342, 37.7898));
    nodes.add(new SKCoordinate(-122.4141, 37.7898));
    nodes.add(new SKCoordinate(-122.4342, 37.7753));
    polyline.setNodes(nodes);
    // set polyline color
    polyline.setColor(new float[]{0.976470588f, 0.003921569f, 0.580392157f, 1f});

    polyline.setLineSize(10);
    polyline.setIdentifier(12);
    mapView.addPolyline(polyline);
```

I used the function 1f = 255 then 0.976470588f = 249
[image]

Comment: thank you very much. do you have an example of the document that shows the proper use of the setColor(float[] array) method? I could not find it

Comment: I don't have any documentation: the array should contain 4 values: R, G, B and Alpha. All values go from 0 (0) to 1 (255) - so if you want to convert values from the 0 - 255 interval to the 0- 1 interval, use the formula: myFloatValue = my0_255Value * 1 / 255. The alpha parameter goes from 0 (fully transparent) to 1 (fully opaque)